# perl regex stop negative look-behind taking away from next greedy capture

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy, negative-lookbehind

Take this simple example in perl v5.22.0:

```
my $data = "foobar\n";
$data =~ s/(?<!bar)(\s*)$/qux$1/;
print $data;
```

It prints:

```
foobar
qux
```

but I didn't expect `$data` to change. I also tried some earlier versions of perl 5.x with the same result.

Conversely, I'd expect this string with the same regex to cause a replacement but it doesn't:

```
my $data = "foobaz\n";
$data =~ s/(?<!bar)(\s*)$/qux$1/;
print $data;
```

I don't understand why this happens. In either one the asterisk is supposed to be greedy. I figured `$1` would be `\n` making the negative look-behind group compare against `bar` in the first example and `baz` in the second example. Regex101 when I use perl says:

> Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.

So in this case is what happens is it gives back to the negative look-behind?

As the title says the real issue is I'd like to stop the look-behind from swallowing that second group. Unfortunately it's not a single letter, that is just for the example to make it easier to understand. Also in perl I'm somewhat limited with what I can do with the negative look-behind, for example "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex". If it's possible I'd like an answer that is compatible with perl 5.8. Thanks

Comment: @Kerwin I see what you're saying but I actually want it to not match if not `bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
$data =~ s/(?<!bar)(?<!\s)(\s*)$/qux$1/;
```

The following version will work with 5.8, and I think it's actually faster (since it jumps to the end of the string and backtracks rather than checking two look behinds at every position):

```
$data =~ s/
   ^
   (
      (?:
         .*
         (?: [^r\s]
         |   [^a] r
         |   [^b] ar
         )
      )?
   )
   ( \s* )
   \z
/${1}qux$2/sx;
```

(`$` could be used instead of `\z`; it's just a micro-optimization.)

---

### Explanation

Without the `m` flag, `$` is equivalent to `(?:\n?\z)`, which it to say it matches at a newline at the end the string and at the end of the string. This means there are two possible places for `$` to match `foobar␊`

```
foobar␊      (There's a LF at position 6 in
01234567      case your font can't show it.)
      ^^
```

`(?<!bar)` prevents the first location from being considered, but it allows the second.

- `(?<!bar)(\s*)$` matches 0 characters at position 7, because

  - `(?<=bar)` matches 0 characters at position 7.
  - `(\s*)` matches 0 characters at position 7.
  - `$` matches 0 characters at position 7.

It's the only possible match, so greediness is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

it really matched the last position, before the position is `\n`,and after it is `$`,now look your regex :

```
(?<!bar)(\s*)$
```

before the position is not `bar`:matched

after the position is `$`,matched `(\s*)$`